# Set Bridge Adapter for Virtualbox VM on MacOS 10

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have a 2018 macbook pro with 10.14 OS. I tried to set up a Virtualbox VM with Ubuntu through Bridge-adapter mode (need the VM been seen on network). My macbook is connected to network through WiFi.

I have tested all available bridge adapter name (en0 WiFi, en5 USB Ethernet, en1-en4 thunderbolt, brdige0, ap1, p2p0, and awdl0). With or without promiscuous mode and cable connected or not.

None of the above seems to work. I enter the VM and can't ping any websites.

Comment: bridge mode would require that you have an extra IP.  What's your network, home, work, school environment?  It's possible that your switch has a security restriction for one IP per port.

Comment: My network is work with Comcast Bussiness. I am connecting it through WIFI. How do I find out if I have extra IP or restricted?

Comment: If you have internal wifi, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That's the part I really don't get. I think it should be no problem too. Is there any way that I could diagnose further?

Comment: same problem here, just don't forget by default you can't ping your macOS